# Enable mouse scroll in Emacs running in the terminal

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal, emacs24

When I try to scroll when I have emacs running inside terminal the whole terminal scrolls instead of only the buffer in emacs.

Is it possible to change this? I'm using Emacs 24.3.1 on OSX 10.9.1

I've tried `M-x xterm-mouse-mode` and

having

`(require 'mouse)`
    `(xterm-mouse-mode t)`
    `(mouse-wheel-mode t)`

in my .emacs file, neither works.

Comment: What's your system? I have no issue on Ubuntu 13.10. Also it's much better to run Emacs as GUI than in terminal.

Comment: Emacs 24.3.1 on OSX 10.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is specific to Apple's default Terminal app. You can:

- Install SIMBL and [MouseTerm](https://bitheap.org/mouseterm/)
- Use iTerm2